# Views counter incrementing only for different users using cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to implement a views counter on my website. JavaScript should ask the server to increase the views count in the databank iff the person has not visited the page before. The information on whether the person has already visited the site should be stored in a cookie. Here is my code (which only works once after deleting all cookies):

```
function viewsAdd() {
if (cookieGet("viewed")=="" || cookieGet("viewed")=="False") {
// send view to server
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
    cookieSet("viewed", "True", 365);
};
var URL = encodeURIComponent(location.href.replace(location.origin,''));
xhr.open('POST', "website.com/viewsAddToTheDatabankFor"+"?URL="+URL, true);
xhr.send();
}
```

My suspicion is that when I save a cookie `"viewed=True"` for the page

```
website.com/blog/nature
```

then this cookie is shared with subpages on a deeper level and so the code does not increment the counter for the subpages:

```
website.com/blog/nature/Amazonia
website.com/blog/nature/Atlantic
```

Is this observation true, and if yes, how do I go about fixing this problem?

Comment: As long as the cookie path being set is `/` then it should not care about the rest of the URL, `blog/nature/Atlantic`?

Comment: On mozilla developer page it says **The %x2F ("/") character is considered a directory separator, and subdirectories match as well.**

Comment: https://flaviocopes.com/cookies/#set-a-cookie-path _"This means that to apply a global cookie from an inner page, you need to specify `path=/`."_

Comment: I think you should create a Session Cookie. Everyone gets a uniq cookie that's apply to all pages. Then on the server side you keep track of what pages that cookie have visited.

Comment: So there is no way to have a unique cookie for each child url which is not shared with parents?